# How come this system of particles keeps increasing in energy?

Tags: c, physics

I have a system of particles. They have acceleration, velocity and position.

When a particle hits to the wall, its velocity flips. When two particles approach to each other, they repel each other with this force:

```
F=1/r^2
```

or

```
F_x=delta(x)/r^3
F_y=delta(y)/r^3
```

When the system was running, I was feeling the total speed of all particles are increasing. Which is strange. A particle should give its energy to 
another one. So, the total energy of the system must keep constant.

The kinetic energy of the system is equal to

```
E_k=Sigma v^2
```

I kept monitoring the total energy of the entire system and print it via `cout` and I observe that it keeps increasing. It contradicts the conservativeness of energy. Where am I making mistake inside the code?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t N=1000;

struct Point
{
    double x, y;
    double v_x, v_y;
    double a_x, a_y;
};
Point points[N];

void next_frame()
{
    double energy=0.0;

    // calculate forces
    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        double fx=0.0,fy=0.0;

        for( size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j )
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                double dx=points[i].x-points[j].x;
                double dy=points[i].y-points[j].y;
                double r2=dx*dx+dy*dy;
                if(r2>0.01 && r2<100.0) // avoid nan and also unnecessary computation
                {
                    // F=1/r^2
                    double r=sqrt(r2);
                    fx+=dx/(r*r*r);
                    fy+=dy/(r*r*r);
                }
            }
        }

        points[i].a_x=0.01*fx;
        points[i].a_y=0.01*fy;
        energy+=points[i].v_x*points[i].v_x+points[i].v_y*points[i].v_y;
    }
    std::cout<<energy<<std::endl;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        // integrations
        points[i].v_x += points[i].a_x;
        points[i].v_y += points[i].a_y;
        points[i].x += points[i].v_x;
        points[i].y += points[i].v_y;

        // wall
        if( points[i].x < -50.0 )
            points[i].v_x = +std::abs(points[i].v_x);
        else if( points[i].x > +50.0 )
            points[i].v_x = -std::abs(points[i].v_x);

        if( points[i].y < -50.0 )
            points[i].v_y = +std::abs(points[i].v_y);
        else if( points[i].y > +50.0 )
            points[i].v_y = -std::abs(points[i].v_y);

    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // initialize particles
    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        Point p;
        p.x = -50 + ((rand() % 1000)/1000.0)*100.0;
        p.y = -50 + ((rand() % 1000)/1000.0)*100.0;
        p.a_x=0.0;
        p.a_y=0.0;
        p.v_x=0.001*((rand() % 1000)/1000.0-0.5);
        p.v_y=0.001*((rand() % 1000)/1000.0-0.5);
        points[i]=p;
    }   

    while(1)
    {
        next_frame();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the energy profile over iterations:

[image: Energy]

---

Please avoid changing tags of this question.

If I ask this question in a physics forum, they will tell me it is a programming problem not physics.

Comment: You're missing a God particle :P

Comment: Assuming your math is correct you might be accumulating numerical errors.

Comment: Also your discretization technique might be faulty, you could check this by increasing and decreasing the resolution to see if the resolution changes the outcome.

Comment: Kinetic is increasing, potential energy is decreasing. What's wrong with that? You've got an attractive force (negative energy field), that's always happening.

Comment: @lorro, but kinetic energy seems to increase until infinity. There must be an equilibrium somewhere. Statistically, the potential energy is not decreasing. Because the system is enclosed inside a box.

Comment: Try running your code with `N=2` and see what happens.   That is a case where you can calculate what is expected by hand, and compare.

Comment: @Peter, with `N=2` the energy is very low but fluctuating. Statistically constant. With `N=3` the energy is fluctuating and in total it is growing.

Comment: In fact, try it with N=1

Comment: @doctorlove, with `N=1` it is fine. Absolutely constant.

Comment: Never use an Euler method if you want numerically sensible results over long time scales. Use the classical order 4 Runge-Kutta method, or the order 2 Verlet method or its modification to an order 4 method.

Comment: if(r2>0.01 && r2<100.0) so the particles don't interact at all when r goes to 10. Looks a bit stingy to me.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean small `r` should be ignored for not facing with `nan` numbers in the result. large `r` should be ignored to avoid trivial burden of computation when forces are so small. Anyway, deactivating this `if` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Why the `energy` tag?

Comment: It might be a programming problem, but nevertheless your code is not C. It is C++.

Comment: @Gerhardh, only in sense of using `cout` and `std::abs` it is `C++` , however, besides that, fundamentally, I have only used `C` concepts.

Comment: It is the cout. For indetermination principle, if you look the system you are going to alterate him. If you do not cout, you are going to have a stable system.

Comment: Without jokes, I  do not know if this is the case, but I hade I similar problem when I wrote my mechanical symulator. At each loop, gave the acceleration gave by the balancing of the forces I had to update speed and position. So guess what? I must use the derivative and not the integral form of the equations. So I do not remember so much about particle dynamic, but if these are integral form, it could be a clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-interpreted the multiplication of the force by 0.01 as using a time step of dt=0.01. Then the velocities used are actually 0.01 times the real velocities. To extract this implicit treatment of the time step, initialize the velocities with a factor 100 times larger,

```
        p.v_x=0.1*((rand() % 1000)/1000.0-0.5);
        p.v_y=0.1*((rand() % 1000)/1000.0-0.5);
```

and remove the factor between force and acceleration

```
        points[i].a_x=fx;
        points[i].a_y=fy;
```

Then apply the time step during the integration. ([Velocity] Verlet is symplectic Euler with slightly different initial values. Because of the random initialization, this does not matter in this case.)

```
        points[i].v_x += points[i].a_x*dt;
        points[i].v_y += points[i].a_y*dt;
        points[i].x += points[i].v_x*dt;
        points[i].y += points[i].v_y*dt;
```

---

To avoid singularities in a smooth and almost physical way change the potential to use the modified radius

```
r2 = dx*dx + dy*dy + 1e-2; r=sqrt(r2);
```

Then you can remove the conditional evaluation. Add the summation of the potential energies inside this same loop

```
            double r2=dx*dx + dy*dy + 1e-2;
           // V=1/r, F=1/r^2
            double r=sqrt(r2);
            fx+=dx/(r*r*r);
            fy+=dy/(r*r*r);
            potential += 1/r;
```

and in the output also combine the kinetic and potential energies. With these changes I get an output like

```
kin= 1.70606,    pot= 29897.4,   tot= 29899.1
kin= 3.28869,    pot= 29895.9,   tot= 29899.2
kin= 7.98328,    pot= 29891.3,   tot= 29899.2
kin= 15.4178,    pot= 29884.1,   tot= 29899.5
kin= 24.9195,    pot= 29875,     tot= 29900
kin= 35.686,     pot= 29864.9,   tot= 29900.6
kin= 47.0385,    pot= 29854.2,   tot= 29901.3
kin= 58.5285,    pot= 29843.4,   tot= 29901.9
kin= 69.9214,    pot= 29832.6,   tot= 29902.5
kin= 81.1222,    pot= 29822,     tot= 29903.1
kin= 92.1124,    pot= 29811.5,   tot= 29903.6
kin= 102.946,    pot= 29801.1,   tot= 29904
kin= 113.739,    pot= 29790.6,   tot= 29904.4
kin= 124.69,     pot= 29779.9,   tot= 29904.6
kin= 136.055,    pot= 29768.8,   tot= 29904.9
kin= 147.937,    pot= 29757.3,   tot= 29905.2
kin= 160.059,    pot= 29745.7,   tot= 29905.7
```

or as graph

[image: energy graph]

As one can see that, while the kinetic energy steadily grows, the total energy moves only very slowly. This latter may have two sources,

- the almost exactly preserved quantity of symplectic integration methods is a modified energy function and
- the reflection at the boundaries may introduce small jumps in that modified energy that sum up to a steady if small change in the total energy.

Comment: multiplication of the force by 0.01 can be interpreted as m=0.01 too. However, the main problem is the step size. Thanks for adding the potential energy.

Comment: I made some modification and created a new [code](http://pastebin.com/K5hQafWc). Now, I see a decline in the total energy according to the [profile](https://s30.postimg.org/oon7dyj4h/aaaaa.png). Where do you see the problem?

Comment: You are counting the potential energies twice. Before that was no problem since you also computed twice the kinetic energy. But now that you want to be physically correct, either add only if `i<j` or add `0.5/r`. -- Cutting the potential off by setting it to zero seems drastic, you could also use `r2=max(0.01,r2)` to get a continuous and bounded potential.

Comment: Thanks, now, total energy is constant but half of what you have obtained. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnErQ.png)

Comment: Yes, that is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The energy can increase when particles get very close to each other.
Everything would work OK if you took infinitesimally small steps.
But if you take a finite size step, a particle jumps from one point in space to another.
If it happens to jump right next to another particle its repulsion force `F_x=delta(x)/r^3` will be very large, which represents a an increase in potential energy that it should not have got. If the step were broken down into smaller steps the particles would have slowed down and not got so close.

I don't know of a solution. But maybe if you detect an increase in energy on a step, then the step could be recursively subdivided into smaller steps.

Comment: Or add  a magic fridge. When total heat goes above a certain value, scale everything down a notch.

Comment: The problem is alleviated by decreasing the time step. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your physics equations are supposed to be

```
F = dr / r^3
a = 0.01 * F
v += a * dt
x += v * dt
```

Where `dt` is the simulation timestep. You do not multiply by `dt` in your second loop that updates particles. That is wrong.

Also your solution method is unstable. You have to choose the timestep to preserve stability. Since your system eventually stabilizes you could just experiment with it.

So suggested action is:

1. Introduce a new variable `dt`
2. Change the second loop to look like

   ```
   points[i].v_x += dt * points[i].a_x;
   points[i].v_y += dt * points[i].a_y;
   points[i].x += dt * points[i].v_x;
   points[i].y += dt * points[i].v_y;
   ```

I have experimented with a small number of particles in 1D and found that 
`dt = 0.001` looks fine for my bunch of 100 particles.